# Pulling analog DC output from a laptop

Tags: power-supply, analog, laptop

I am using a laser source that can accept analog input (0-5 V) to set light intensity levels.  The input impedance of this driving voltage is 50 Ohms.  Typically this is connected to a function generator to create sinusoidal modulations of the light level.

I don't care about AC light signals; I just want to set a DC light signal by providing a level somewhere between 0 (off) and 5 Volts , and I want to be able to do this remotely.

I could use an Arduino or Labjack to drive this signal, but I was wondering if there was a component-free solution that could just use the laptop, analog circuit elements, and some programming.

A couple of ideas I daydreamed about were:

1. Program the speakers to play a tone that I could connect to the laser source via the headphone jack.  (Soft tone would be faint light, loud would be bright).  This would seem to involve a bit of work as the headphone jack voltage is too low (~0.3 V) and the output impedance is also about 10 Ohms.
2. Program the RS232 port in conjunction with a voltage divider.  This would involve a bit of work as I don't know how easy it is to program pins directly.
3. Program the USB output power.  After googling around for a bit, this seems tricky to do with Windows.

If anyone has a good idea how to generate an analog 0-5V output from a computer, or could comment on the ideas above, please advise.

Comment: How fast do you need to change your control voltage?

Comment: not fast, once every few seconds at most.

Comment: I mean dV/dt. What is your requirement? Or, when in use with function generator, what is your fastest frequency for intensity modulation?

Comment: There's no requirement, really.  If it takes one second to switch from 1 to 5 Volts, that's totally acceptable.  One microsecond would be fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a cable of some sort to connect ANY type of solution to the laptop so consider starting with a cable of the type suggested in the answer by @TonyM. Such cable could be the [TTL-232R-5V-WE](http://www.mouser.com/_/?Keyword=TTL-232R-5V-WE) available from the likes of Mouser.

This cable is a USB to serial port converter with 0-5V swing at the output signals. It can also source current from the the laptop USB port out a 5V pin. My proposal is a bit simpler that that posed by the other answers. The idea is to use the serial port TxD line to provide a poor mans PWM to the end of the cable. You can send appropriate characters out the serial port such that the average output if mostly low, mid-range or mostly high. For example for mid range send 'U' characters (0x55), for lows send out NULs (0x00) and for highs try DELs (0x7F).

The TxD waveform can then be fed through a series diode into a low pass filter. The filter would have its own discharge resistor to establish the low level bias of the filter output. The baud rate at which you stuff data out to the TxD pin would want to be high with respect to the time constants of the low pass filter. This filtered signal would then be used to drive the input of an op-amp driver component that is powered from the 5V line and capable of driving the input impedance of the laser device. A rail to rail output op-amp is the best choice here.

Answer (score 1):

The 0..5V control voltage needs to drive 50 ohms, meaning that it needs to be capable of supplying 0.1 A. A PC can provide that current from the USB connector but not from the serial port. However, the serial port is easier to programme with than the USB port, or certainly has a shorter learning curve.

You could use an USB-to-LVTTL-serial-port adaptor. This plugs into a PC USB port at one end and gives the 5V supply and the RS232C TxD/RxD signals at LVTTL levels (3.3V). You can get these as a module (look at FTDI) or built into a cable, the latter being less than a fiver.

You can then attach a microcontroller or other IC to receive your RS232-signalled bytes and convert them into an 8-bit parallel byte. This can go to a DAC (may be internal to your microcontroller) and the DAC analogue voltage can go through a power op-amp buffer for the 0.1 A drive strength.

This is one way of doing it and hardly meets your requirement of a few analogue parts. But it does let you make something PC-powered and controlled. You may find microcontroller demo' boards on the Internet that contain some or all of this circuitry for under a ton - have a search around. If you're not microcontroller-minded, this is all somewhat moot.

Answer (score 1):

If your laptop has a serial port then you have two digital output pins that may help you ...They are CTS (Clear to Send) and DTR (Data terminal Ready) . There was an answer on how to tweak these signals [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539104/controlling-dtr-and-rts-pin-of-serial-port-in-c-on-windows-platform). You could also use VB, Python serial or even Powershell scripts to tweak them.

Depending on the chips used to generate the RS232 signals these will swing between +/-3 to +/-12 V and typically have  series resistor of 300 Ohms. If you set both high you may get a substantial enough signal level for your laser. You'd get 25% of the open circuit high voltage so might get as much as 3 V across 50 Ohms.

You'd have to be careful and not set both DTR and CTS to the negative voltage unless you are quite sure that your Laser input could withstand this. 
If you SET DTR high and CTS low you should have about zero volt output with both outputs connected to your Laser, so you only really need to toggle one signal to get a simple Laser on/off signal.

One other thought is that you could use TX data, a low pass filter and a serial diode. If you configure the serial comm port to send 8bit, NP then you could send a continuous stream of characters at say 115k Baud and make yourself a very crude DAC. If you set one of DTR or CTS high then the output would be close to zero. Then characters sent via Tx would give a positive input to the Laser.

For example here is the [datasheet](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3222-MAX3241.pdf) for the Max32xx Rx/Tx.

The device output drivers can supply:

[image]

The output voltage is likely to be somewhat non-linear (some sort of active shutdown) but we know we can supply 35 mA into a short and that the output resistance is 300 Ohms. From that we can deduce that the driving voltage must be approximately 10.5 V. From that I might expect to be able to drive the 50 Ohm load to about 1.5 V with a single driver.
So for the CTS/DTR solution you would expect around 3 V into 50 Ohm. For the Tx solution 1.5 V and you could use CTS/DTR to scale to 3 V or higher.

Comment: That's very clever with the TX data trick.  I wonder if you would see the resultant laser flicker with a sufficiently sensitive detector.

Comment: If you put a low pass filter on the serial output then I'd suggest you would not see the variations....but if you left out the low pass filter you could possibly use it for communications too.....

Comment: This is called PWM converter. But for 100 mA drive at 5V, you will need some medium-power OpAmp/ Buffer to drive the 50-Ohm load.

Comment: @AliChen. Since the rs232 chip is current limited output....that can be used as the driver....not further active device would be needed even to drive the 50 Ohm load.